# Upload files in server using Meteor Files veliov group

Tags: file, meteor, server, nodemailer

I have this package nodemailer used in Meteor. 
After getting the emails, I would like to save the attachments using Meteor Files. 
The problem is I don't know how. Can anyone provide a simple example for uploading files in server code. I tried uploading in the client and successful. But when i tried Files.insert() in server, it have "not a function" error.

Here is my code in server,

```
var mailparser = new MailParser({
    streamAttachments: true
});
Fiber(function() { 
    var timeStamp = Math.floor(Date.now());
    mailparser.on("attachment", function(attachment, mail){
        ... code here to upload
        mailparser.on("end", Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (mail_object) {
            .... some code here
        }));
        mailparser.write(data);
        mailparser.end();
        client.dele(msgnumber);     
    }).run();
```

Comment: In your description you mention "when I tried Fiels.insert().." but this isn't in the code you supplied

Comment: This is fixed now . I used write function of Files.

Comment: @JMA would you please share your solution as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because insert function is for client side only, I used write() function of Files API. Here is the link,
https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/wiki/Write